# verilog HDLCompiler 806 error near <=

Tags: verilog, hdl

so i have this code in verilog and i don;t know wwere is the problem ? 
in the statment of the "if", in the conditions, in the registers, i dont know please help me

here is the code and the error mesages :

```
module top(
    input [31:0] din,
    output [31:0] dout
    );

reg [4:0] i, j;
reg [31:0] max =0;
reg [4:0] cnt;
reg [4:0] comp;


for(i=0; i<=31; i=i+1) begin
    if(din[i]== 1'b0) begin
        comp <= comp;
        end

        else if(din[i]==1 & din[i+1]==1) begin
            cnt<=cnt+1;
            if(cnt>comp) begin
                comp<=cnt;
                end else begin
                    comp<=comp;
                    end
                end 
            end
```

the problems that apear on and on and on are:

> INFO:HDLCompiler:1845 - Analyzing Verilog file "D:/ProiecteISE/verilog proj/teme 2016/tema1/top.v" into library work
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme2016/tema1/top.v" Line 34: Syntax error near "<=".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme2016/tema1/top.v" Line 38: Syntax error near "<=".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme2016/tema1/top.v" Line 40: Syntax error near "<=".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme2016/tema1/top.v" Line 42: Syntax error near "<=". ERROR:ProjectMgmt -
>   4 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.

and if i erase the ";" in the lines with errors, its apears like this:

```
module top(
    input [31:0] din,
    output [31:0] dout
    );

reg [4:0] i, j;
reg [31:0] max =0;
reg [4:0] cnt;
reg [4:0] comp;


for(i=0; i<=31; i=i+1) begin
    if(din[i]== 0) begin
        comp <= comp
        end
        else if(din[i]==1 & din[i+1]==1) begin
            cnt<=cnt+1
            if(cnt>comp) begin
                comp<=cnt
                end else begin
                    comp<=comp
                    end
                end 
            end





endmodule
```

and get only one error

INFO:HDLCompiler:1845 - Analyzing Verilog file "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme 2016/tema1/top.v" into library work
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Proiecte ISE/verilog proj/teme 2016/tema1/top.v" Line 34: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:ProjectMgmt - 1 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.

Comment: Please do not add lots of extra information in unformatted comments. Instead, please [edit] the question to include the extra in a way that is easy to read.

Comment: thanks for the advice, its my first question

Comment: solved myself, i should insert "alwasy@(*) begin" before the "for"

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need the semicolons to terminate each assignment/operation, so getting rid of them isn't the correct fix.

The error is complaining that it doesn't understand the `<=` symbol. This is because you're using a style of assignments that are only valid inside an `always` or `initial` block.

Wrap your `for` loop in an `always@(*)` if your looking to do combinational logic (at which point you should use blocking assignments `=`), or an `always@(posedge clk)` block if you're doing sequential logic.

For example:

```
always@(*) begin
    for(i=0; i<=31; i=i+1) begin
         ....
    end
end
```